# Get image from web and display it in ImageView using jsoup

Tags: android, jsoup

I want to display the banners on this page : http://abcsur.info/clasificados/inmuebles/casas

this is my code for get it

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
Elements img = document.select("div.col-sm-12.A4DZP4C3.well.leaderboard-A4DZP4C3.genericContainer.js-A4DZP4C3.js-leaderboard-A4DZP4C3");
            // Locate the src attribute
            String imgSrc = img.attr("src");
            // Download image from URL
            InputStream input = new java.net.URL(imgSrc).openStream();
            // Decode Bitmap
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
```

and for display it in ImageView

```
 ImageView logoimg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.publicidad);
        logoimg.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Dont work.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setImageBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap)' on a null object reference
        at info.blacktrail.abcsur.InmueblesFolder.Casas$Title.onPostExecute(Casas.java:135)
        at info.blacktrail.abcsur.InmueblesFolder.Casas$Title.onPostExecute(Casas.java:76)
```

Comment: Debug and resolve `bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);` Its null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ImageView logoimg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.publicidad);
logoimg.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

In the above code `logoimg` is null.